# Array of LinkedList of Arrays

Tags: java, collections

I have a `Text File` having following lines

```
1) 2,3 3,2 4,5

2) 1,3 4,2 6,13

3) 1,2 4,2 5,5

4) 1,5 2,2 3,2 5,4 7,3 6,6
```

The number of lines of the text file is known (i,e 4). The pair digits (for eg : 2,3) are variable for each line. Whereas the pair digit corresponds to the property.

So, to represent these values i am planning to have an array of linked list of an array.

The reason for this choice of mine is that:

1 : `Since i know the number of lines is 4. So it will be an array`.

2 : `Each line has a variable number of pairs. So, i will have a linked list representation for it`.

3 : `The pair values each represents a property so i will have an array size two for it. One index for each property`.

Considering the above three points, I will have an `Array(size 4) of LinkedList of an Array(size 2)`.

Here is how i have represented this in Java(I am new to Java and i have to confess that i do not know yet if its correct ).

```
static ArrayList<Integer[]>[] graph = (ArrayList<Integer[]>[]) new ArrayList[200];
```

Now, considering my above graph variable has been initialized properly can some one tell me how can i populate it with the data. If you have some other advice regarding the initialization or how i have conceptually broken the problem in 3 points please share.

Comment: What's holding you back from populating it with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your thinking process is comprehensible, I think you have come to incorrect decisions (maybe caused by your lack of Java experience) - here are the answers I suggest:

1. You know that the number of lines is constant with a known constant, but using arrays in Java directly is mostly not useful, use `ArrayList` instead. It is a `List` (a tuple) implemented using an array.
2. Your thought on modeling the pairs of variable amount as a list seems very good and I would agree to this. You should, however, not use a `LinkedList` for this purpose, as it is generally slower than an `ArrayList`. Both implementations satisfy the `List` interface so you can use them interchangeable.
3. You could model the pairs themselves as two element arrays, but to make the semantics more understandable, you should invent a documented data class for the two parts.

Now, let's assume the container type would look like this (you should give the variables and the class itself better names):

```
class Pair {
  public final int a;
  public final int b;

  Pair(int a, int b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

You could then create your data structure with:

```
final int lines = 42; // the number of lines
List<List<Pair>> data = new ArrayList<List<Pair>>(lines);
```

And fill it with data using

```
for(String line : input){
  final List<Pair> lineList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  lineList.addAll(extractPairsFromLine(line));
  data.add(lineList);
}
```

where `extractPairsFromLine` is a method taking a `String` and returning a `List<Pair>`.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I'd keep it simple. Just use something like

```
List<List<List<Integer>>>
```

or even better, create your own class for the inner types.

```
List<PairList>
```

or something like that, where `PairList` extends (or contains) an `ArrayList<Pair>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Collection framework.**

`ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>`